# How can I track a single branch on subversion with git

Tags: svn, git, git-branch

I'd like to track a remote branch on SVN from within Git. I can see the basics of how to do this with the git-svn command, I was hoping to do something like the following:

```
Git branch | SVN branch
-----------------------
master     | Trunk
feature1   | <not mapped>
feature2   | <not mapped>
```

so that once I merge into git/master, and then do dcommit, Trunk would be updated with only changes between the last svn commit and the git/HEAD.

Is this possible? how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`git svn` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) describes working with Subversion's trunk, but with a dirty master:

> ```
> # Clone a repo (like git clone):
>     git svn clone http://svn.example.com/project/trunk
> # Enter the newly cloned directory:
>     cd trunk
> # You should be on master branch, double-check with 'git branch'
>     git branch
> # Do some work and commit locally to git:
>     git commit ...
> # Something is committed to SVN, rebase your local changes against the
> # latest changes in SVN:
>     git svn rebase
> # Now commit your changes (that were committed previously using git) to SVN,
> # as well as automatically updating your working HEAD:
>     git svn dcommit
> # Append svn:ignore settings to the default git exclude file:
>     git svn show-ignore >> .git/info/exclude
> ```

To do your work on feature branches instead of master

```
git checkout -b feature1
hack ...
git add ...
git commit ...
```

When you're ready to get your work back into Subversion, be sure to keep your history linear:

```
git checkout master
git svn rebase
git rebase master feature1
git checkout master
git merge feature1
```

Ship it!

```
git svn dcommit
```